# Чай, чайка и чаять

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Эти слова очень похожи и производят впечатление однокоренных. Но так ли это? Особенно интересует сходство слов "чай" и "чайка". Есть ли между ними родство? А между "чайкой" и "чаять"?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Родственные связи между этими словами этимологами не обнаруживаются.

ЧАЙ
Слово чай вместе с чаепитием пришло в русский язык в середине 17 века, причем сначала чай считался лекарственным растением. Слово заимствовано непосредственно из китайского языка (cha - сев.-китайск. - чай), так как в это время уже установились прочные связи Московского государства с Китайской империей.

ЧАЙКА
Это исконное слово, образовано от звукоподражания "чаи". В современной форме слово известно с 18 века, в др.-рус. варианте это чаица (упоминается в "Слове о полку Игореве").

ЧАЯТЬ
Чаять - от ст.-сл. "чаяти" - ожидать, надеяться. Некоторые языковеды считают родственными слова час и чаяти/чати. Можно сравнить: ждать - погодить.